# whats wrong with this format?

Tags: php, mysql

something is wrong with my code formatting i believe
i am still unsure of what is happening that gives this error,

i am getting the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '('

here is my code

```
<?php
$runamazonapi = false;
if $runamazonapi = true 
{
"run this code"
else
}  
//do nothing
{
    ?>
```

i am getting the following error on line 3 or at this part
if $runamazonapi = true

thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: that's not a valid php syntax. try either `if($runamazonapi)` or `if($runamazonapi == true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$runamazonapi = false;
if ($runamazonapi == true) 
{
    "run this code"
} 
else 
//do nothing
{

}
?>
```

Comment: Note for OP: This is the way to go. But if you got this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' ... on line xxx`, replace `"run this code"` with something like `echo "yes it works!"`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of syntactical errors with your code, but the error means that the php parser expected to find an `(` but instead found a variable.  You need `()` around the if statement condition and you need a closing `}` on the first `if` condition.  Also, you need to use the proper `{}` to open and close the else clause:

```
<?php
$runamazonapi = false;
if ($runamazonapi = true)
{
"run this code"
}
else
{  
//do nothing
}
    ?>
```

Also, what you have won't work.  You're *assigning* `$runamazonapi` to true, not checking if it is true.  You need to use `==` not `=`:

```
<?php
$runamazonapi = false;
if ($runamazonapi == true)
{
"run this code"
}
else
{  
//do nothing
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Also, watch for assignment in the condition.

Comment: @Wiseguy yup, caught that myself second read through, there are a number of problems with that code...

Comment: @Wiseguy lol thanks for the heads up, I was only looking at the error and then started to parse through the rest of the mess...I think my code is good now...

Comment: long story short, this whole mess probably wasn't worth bothering with :-p

Comment: @Wiseguy jeeze, you're not kidding.  I actually could have rewritten it in less time.  Teach me to copy/paste...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 if($runamazonapi){
 //run code
 }else{
 //do something
 }
```